# Question about Logistic Regression - 4

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I am currently studying on logistic regression. So I have found a document on the Internet explaining about it.

Somehow, it explains Bernoulli distribution in the beginning and I am having a problem to understand the equation below. I can refer to the variance explanation in wikipedia, it is still not clear for me to understand. I am new to this, and reading the paper line by line. If you think you can give me an explanation, I will be really grateful.

I hope I have provided enough information for you to give me an explanation.

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expected value, sum the values times the probabilities of the values:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[Y_i]
&=\mathrm{P}[Y_i=0]\cdot0+\mathrm{P}[Y_i=1]\cdot1\\
&=(1-\pi_i)\cdot0+\pi_i\cdot1\\
&=\pi_i
\end{align}
$$
The variance is the mean of the squares minus the square of the mean. The mean of the squares is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[Y_i^2]
&=\mathrm{P}[Y_i=0]\cdot0^2+\mathrm{P}[Y_i=1]\cdot1^2\\
&=(1-\pi_i)\cdot0+\pi_i\cdot1\\
&=\pi_i
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}[Y_i]
&=\mathrm{E}[Y_i^2]-\mathrm{E}[Y_i]^2\\
&=\pi_i-\pi_i^2\\
&=\pi_i(1-\pi_i)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: When I first read the question, I didn't see that $y_i$ was restricted to $\{0,1\}$ and thought this was a generalization to continuous $y_i\in[0,1]$. The computation of the mean and variance were much more difficult, involving negative powers of $\log\left(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}\right)$. Then I saw the restriction... doh!

Comment: Now I see that my answer is simply an completion of Avitus' answer (without the discussion of logistic regression, which I don't know is relevant to the current computation).

Comment: There was a very minor typo in your answer. I hope that I have not been wrong taking the freedom of fixing it instead of disturbing you. Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: thanks for catching that!

Comment: When small things like this one happen to me, they make my day (I am almost blind) ! Thanks for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $Y_i$ is random variable which  assumes the values $\{0,1\}$. So, for all $i$, $y_i\in\{0,1\}$. Then $P(Y_i = 1):=\pi_i$ and $P(Y_i = 0)= 1-P(Y_i = 1)= 1-\pi_i.$
You can summarize these information in

$$P(Y_i = y_i):=\pi^{y_i}_i(1-\pi_i)^{1-y_i}.$$

This notation is not precise as, in the context of logistic regression, one should consider conditional probabilities
$$P(Y_i = 1)| X = x_i):=\pi(x_i,\beta)$$

instead, where  $\pi(x_i,\beta)$ is defined using the inverse of the logit function.
Explicitly
$$\pi_i(x_i,\beta)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\langle \beta, x_i\rangle}}.$$
In summary

$$E(Y_i)=\sum_{j=0}^1 y_j P(Y_i = j) = 1\cdot P(Y_i = 1) + 0\cdot P(Y_i = 0) =\pi_i.  $$

Similar considerations hold for the variance.